# How to convert DataTable output to custom model?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a function that makes a request:

```
public DataTable getById(int id)
{
   return db.GetDataTable("");
}
```

And calling this as:

```
var obj = getById(1);
```

Also I have custom model with `set/get` properties. How to convert output `var obj` into my custom data?

Comment: Generally speaking, your `obj` is `DataTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's all the information you have, then you'll have to convert it yourself.

You could use LINQ to iterate over the rows collection:

```
var results = getById(1);

return results.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Person
                                            {
                                                Name = row.Field<String>("Name"),
                                                Age = row.Field<Int32>("Age")
                                            });
```

You'll have to customize this for your actual class and data.

Comment: Where `new Person` is my model object?

Comment: Can I return to variable instean return.results?

Comment: DataTable does not contain `AsEnumerable`

Comment: I dont have this reference: `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;`

Comment: I tried any way, but I can not use this reference? How to add DLL then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151842/discussion-between-opv-and-grant-winney).

Comment: Then how to get dat from `result`? Because it is enumerable model